# Support of different test profiles for quarkus

Tags: quarkus

Is there any support for different test profiles? During my local tests I would like to use "mvn package" which uses the "test" profile. This points to my localhost db. For my devops toolchain I want to use a different test profile because we are using containers and cannot use localhost. Goal is to distinguish between local machine test and cloud env. test.

Answer (score 2):

you mean you run 'mvn packge' which leads to the tests being run - like with 'mvn test' . In this case @QuarkusTest tests will run with the 'test' profile. The same goes for running tests in the ide.

There is a system property (used with '-D') 'quarkus.test.profile'. It leads to this profile being activated:

```
mvn test -Dquarkus.test.profile=foo
.....
2020-04-10 14:06:20,451 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.3.0.Final started in 17.408s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8081
2020-04-10 14:06:20,451 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile foo activated.
```

You may set this property on the surefire or failsafe plugin in your pom.xml (see [1](https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling)).

You may also set this property within your IDE on a run/launch configuration to start the test (IntelliJ: use the vm options field and add  '-Dquarkus.test.profile=integrate')

https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus supports [custom profiles](https://quarkus.io/guides/application-configuration-guide#configuration-profiles). You have two ways to set a custom profile: via the `quarkus-profile` system property or the `QUARKUS_PROFILE` environment variable.

For your needs, you can for example, use a 'staging' profile with a different db address in `application.properties` in this way:

```
%staging.db.address=value
```

And set the `QUARKUS_PROFILE` environment variable to `staging` to activate the profile.

Answer (score 0):

you can use quarkus.profile property so at runtime it will be:`mvn package -Dquarkus.profile=your_custom_profile`

Comment: `quarkus.profile` will only work for non-testing evironment, `quarkus.test.profile` is the way to go

Comment: thank you @DmytroChaban was searching for a long time